# Is there an Ubuntu alternative for Windows' Battery Report?

Tags: power-management, battery

Do we have a Linux/Ubuntu alternative for Windows' battery report where running `powercfg /batteryreport` on Windows' command prompt generates an actual html file showing the complete battery run time of the machine?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, there isn't really a command line that , but I can make one. Does it have to be specifically HTML ? because there exists already GUI application that does something similar

Comment: Posted an answer, please check

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is already an app that can show you graphical report of battery status. It is called `Gnome Power Statistics` and can be started via terminal as `gnome-power-statistics` or via searching Unity Dash. Here's how it looks like:

[image]

---

In case you insist on using HTML report and viewing it in your browser, here is a script that I made within 20 minutes or so, that displays battery info in your default browser.

```py
import subprocess
import os

devs = [ line for line in subprocess.check_output(['upower','--enumerate']).decode().split('\n') ]
battery = [ item.strip() for item in devs if 'BAT' in item ]
report = subprocess.check_output(['upower','-i',battery[0]])
top = """
<html>
<header><title>This is title</title></header>
<body>
"""
bottom = """
</body>
</html>
"""

with open('report.html','w') as f:
    f.write(top)
    for line in report.decode().split('\n'):
        f.write('<p>' + line + '</p>\n' )
    f.write(bottom)

pid = subprocess.Popen(['xdg-open','report.html']).pid
```

Save this as `simple_battery_report.py` and run as

```
LC_ALL=C python  simple_battery_report.py`
```

And here's how it looks:

[image]

Note, this is not the most efficient solution, it doesn't refresh its information. I would strongly recommend using that other GUI app.

---

For command line enthusiasts here's this:

```
$ LC_ALL=C upower --enumerate |  awk '/BAT/'| xargs upower -i                                                            
  native-path:          BAT1
  vendor:               TOSHIBA
  model:                PABAS0241231
  serial:               0000000000000E6A
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              2016年08月26日 星期五 21时58分27秒 (117 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               fully-charged
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              35.2388 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         35.2536 Wh
    energy-full-design:  44.104 Wh
    energy-rate:         0.0148 W
    voltage:             16.887 V
    percentage:          100%
    capacity:            79.9329%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-full-charged-symbolic'
```

Comment: *"Note, this is not the most efficient solution, it doesn't refresh its information. I would strongly recommend using that other GUI app."* – not to mention that the GUI app has nice graphs about charge/discharge prediction accuracy!